# How to create a new table using groupby and remove duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'd like to create a new dataset, but I'm having a trouble rearranging the data.
My current dataset looks like image below.

```
id        result 
309209    Successful 
309241    Successful 
309241    Not Successful 
309241    Not Successful 
309241    Not Successful
```

I'd like to separate 'Successful' and 'Not Successful' and count each of its instances by ID, which should be changed into something like this below.

```
id       success  fail total
309209   1        0    1
309241   1        3    4
```

I've tried drop.duplicates or groupby to arrange the data and count instances, but I keep getting wrong results. Someone help me with this, please! Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a given `id` is the `status` unique?

Comment: @najeem No, I can just omit status part

Comment: Can you post a sample data which can be copied? Also your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with `margins` and remove last row by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['result'], margins=True, margins_name='total')
         .iloc[:-1]
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .rename(columns={'Not Successful':'fail','Successful':'success'}))
print (df1)

       id  fail  success  total
0  309209     0        1      1
1  309241     3        1      4
```

Another solution with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape and [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for new column `total`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['id','result'])
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .assign(total = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
         .reset_index()
         .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
         .rename(columns={'Not Successful':'fail','Successful':'success'}))
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer, but this gives KeyError: 'id', and I cant' figure out why. :(

Comment: @HyunsooLee - I think `id` is not column, but index, so need change `df = pd.crosstab(df['id'], df['result'], margins=True, margins_name='total')` to `pd.crosstab(df.index, df['result'], margins=True, margins_name='total')`

Comment: Thanks, it works! But sill the problem is the output only gives binary result, giving total value 0 or 1 only. As you can see from part of my data above, it should also print out other values as well :(

Comment: I think success and fail instances of id is printed separately, giving 0 or 1 output only, but I want success and fail instances of an id to be combined.

Comment: @HyunsooLee - Sorry, not understand, because for me it working nice with your dta sample. Problem is with real data? Are dat a confidental?

Comment: I've tried my sample as well and used the exact code you suggested, but don't know why. My real data is not confidential at all.

Comment: @HyunsooLee - Is possible see your data? Can you share it by gdocs, dropbox or send it to my email in my profile?

Answer (score 2):

`df` :

```
    id       result
0   309209  Successful
1   309241  Successful
2   309241  Not Successful
3   309241  Not Successful
4   309241  Not Successful
```

Using [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html)

```
df1 = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.result,columns='result')).groupby('id').sum().reset_index()
df1['total'] = df1[df1.columns[1:]].sum(axis=1)
print(df1)

    id      Not Successful  Successful  total
0   309209  0               1           1
1   309241  3               1           4
```